# Laravel check if all route resourrce params are set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am making a API, i want to check if the posted params (by curl) are equal to de resource params. If not i want to return a json with errors.

How do I get it done to check all route resource parameters?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api' , 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::resource('note' , 'NoteController');
});
```

Comment: I think this can be handled from your controller.You will need to implement that on show/edit/update/destroy. You could use helper function if necessary.

Comment: @ClearBoth, when i leave the id param blank i am getting a route error, MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php, so i need to catch it befor it enters the controller. I think in the route::group but how?!

Comment: @Bas For which method?

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal , i have a curl, for example domain.com/api/note/15, this works, but this doesn't work domain.com/api/note for PUT method , where and how can i check if all required params are set?

Comment: @Bas I think you can add a route for this (to avoid 404 and catch), for eg: `Route::put('domain.com/api/note', 'SomeController@upadte');` Then you will check in the controller whether it has the id.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal Thank you very much that was it. See my answer, correct so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in Exception/Handler.php in method `render`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // check if MethodNotAllowedHttpException exception type using status code 405 or instanceof
    if ($e->getStatusCode() == 405) {

        // custom your response. could be json with 404 or redirect to another page
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'message' => 'not found'], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

more explanation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler)

Comment: @code3rite, thanks, but now i can't return whats going wrong, or is that posible to filter it in the handler and how?

Comment: as shown in my code above, In my example, I filter on `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` and return your custom json response with 404 status code.

Comment: Thanks, this is better than my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

Routes.php

```
Route::put('note', 'NoteController@update');
```

Controller:
$id = null and make a check id check

```
public function update(Request $request, $id = null){
    if($id != null){
       //do stuff
}
```